Why icon not showing on SplashScreen using Jetpack-compose?
I'm try to run SplashScreen api using jetpack compose on android lolipop5.1, the screen background is showing but the icon is not. i'm using splash api 1.0.1.
i'm using a viewmodel to make splash display longer.
class SplashScreenViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val _isLoading = MutableStateFlow(true)
    val isLoading = _isLoading.asStateFlow()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            delay(800)
            _isLoading.value = false
        }
    }
}

Here is the manifest file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@drawable/spotify"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/spotify"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MySplashScreen"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MySplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

Here is the theme.
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MySplashScreen" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/black</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/baseline_pause_24 </item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.AudioApp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.AudioApp" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" />
</resources>

here is MainActivity
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val splashViewModel: SplashScreenViewModel by viewModels()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        installSplashScreen().apply {
            setKeepOnScreenCondition{
                splashViewModel.isLoading.value
            }
        }
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            AudioAppTheme {
                Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                    Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
                        HomeScreen(
                            0f,
                            { },
                            false,
                            Audio(
                                id = 1,
                                audioName = "256",
                                audioUrl = "",
                                audioImage = R.drawable.image1,
                                artistName = "Selena",
                                duration = 250,
                            ),
                            AudioRepositoryImpl().getTrackList(),
                            { },
                            { },
                            {}
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The drawable file

<vector xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:height="24dp" android:tint="#DBDBDB" android:viewportHeight="24" android:viewportWidth="24" android:width="24dp"> <path android:fillColor="@android:color/white" android:pathData="M6,19h4L10,5L6,5v14zM14,5v14h4L18,5h-4z"/> </vector>


I tried using different versions of splash api but it still not showing. I tired to change size of vector but it still not displayed.

What's the content of @drawable/baseline_pause_24?


<path android:fillColor="@android:color/white" android:pathData="M6,19h4L10,5L6,5v14zM14,5v14h4L18,5h-4z"/>


@yamin